# How to measure distribution of high-dimensional data

Tags: data-analysis

I have to methods of projecting random samples in $R^n$ onto a manifold defined by $C(q)=0$, which is a lower-dimensional subset. Now, samples in $R^n$ are uniformly distributed. However, when projecting on to the manifold, the distribution is not guaranteed to be uniform. The two projection methods will provide different distributions.

My question is, what is a good measure of distribution that will enable comparison between the two methods? In simple words, I have two high-dimensional data-sets, how can I compare their distributions?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a uniform distribution on $R^n$?

Comment: A sample is taken such that each dimension is randomly generated in $[-a, a]$. Thus, mean zero.